# Get Exceptions and logs in Jersey SSE Evensource Class

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am using Jersey SSE  eventsource to connect to a Rest api.When any connection error occurs while connecting from client it seem all exceptions are internally handled by Jersey eventSource and it tries reconnecting automatically.I have teh following queries:

1. How can i control this behaviour
2. Can I set a parameter so that the Jersey SSE doesnt automatically reconnect.
3. Is there a way to get the exceptions caught while connecting at eventsource.open so that I can handle it in a customizable manner.
4. EventSource internally uses ExtendedLogger.where will these logs appear?